# Why didn't Dumbledore sent Fawke's feather as a message to the trio explaining the whole plot?

Tags: harry-potter

I believe that Phoenix feathers can be used as a messaging medium (OOTP). Why didn't Dumbledore sent Fawke's feathers as a message for the trio in Deathly Hallows explaining the whole plot?

Comment: He was mildly inconvenienced at this point by death.

Comment: sorry i just read that he left... is there any verifiable source which states that he left?... couldn't Dumbledore have called him back?

Comment: Fawkes is alive, Dumbledore is dead. Fawkes didn't stick around for Dumbledores painting so it's unlikely the painting could summon him.

Answer (score 9):

If we ignore the fact that Dumbledore is dead and that Fawkes has gone... somewhere, the question is still founded on an incorrect assumption. Phoenix feathers can't be used as a "messaging medium". Phoenixes have the ability to make feathers (and possibly other items?) appear in a specific location, but that's it.

Dumbledore knows that the Minister of Magic and Aurors will definitely be arriving at Hogwarts, and he knows that it will be happening soon. He simply asks Fawkes to provide him with a warning precisely when they arrive. Fawkes does this by sending him a feather. It has no message attached, it's just a feather. It only has meaning because the "message" (i.e. the Minister of Magic has arrived) was pre-determined.

It's no different to the red sparks that Harry, Draco and Neville were told to shoot into the air by Hagrid when serving detention in the first book. It means they're in trouble because it was agreed that's what they meant. Without that agreement they're just red sparks.

Comment: That;s not true?? "There was a flash of fire in mid-air, This is not Dumbledore's writing, said Sirius, it must be your mother(Molly Weasely)" Was the message on only a parchment or a Phoenix feather?

Comment: @prakharlondhe That doesn't seem like a full quote. What chapter in Order of the Phoenix is that from?

Comment: I dunno, But its the point where All the weasely children ,along with harry and sirius ,are sitting waiting for their father's fate...

Comment: Then a burst of fire in midair illuminated the dirty plates in front of
them and as they gave cries of shock, a scroll of parchment fell with a
thud onto the table, accompanied by a single golden phoenix tail
feather